# RecyclerView's lags without cause

Tags: android

I have RecyclerView and adapter:

```
public class RVAdapterStats extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> { 
Activity activity; 
private static final String TAG = "VainLog"; 
JSONObject values;

public RVAdapterStats(Activity activity, JSONObject values){
this.activity = activity;
this.values = values;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position){
int solve = 0;
switch (position){
    case 0 : solve = 0;
        break;
    case 1 : solve = 1;
        break;
    case 2 : solve = 2;
        break;
    case 3 : solve = 3;
}
return solve;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh = null;
View itemLayoutView;

switch (viewType)
{
    case 0:
        itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.stats_header, parent, false);
        vh = new ViewHolder0(itemLayoutView);
        break;
    case 1:
        itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.stats_second, parent, false);
        vh = new ViewHolder1(itemLayoutView);
        break;
    case 2: itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.stats_third, parent, false);
        vh = new ViewHolder2(itemLayoutView);
        break;
    case 3: itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.stats_fourth, parent, false);
        vh = new ViewHolder3(itemLayoutView);
}

return vh;
}

@Override

  public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

switch (this.getItemViewType(position)){

    case 0:
        ViewHolder0 holder0 = (ViewHolder0)holder;

        try {
            holder0.player_games_played.setText(values.getString("playerGamesPlayed"));
            holder0.player_games_won.setText(values.getString("playerwinStreak"));
            holder0.player_lifetimegold.setText(values.getString("lifetimeGold"));
            Picasso.with(activity).load(values.getInt("playerSkillTier")).into(holder0.player_skilltier);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;

    case 1:
        ViewHolder1 holder1 = (ViewHolder1)holder;

        try {
        holder1.wins_defeats.setText(values.getString("playerWinDefeat"));
        holder1.winPercent.setText(values.getString("playerWinPercent"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        ViewHolder2 holder2 = (ViewHolder2)holder;
        try {
        List<SliceValue> sliceValue = new ArrayList<>();
        if (values.getInt("blitz")>0) sliceValue.add(new SliceValue(values.getInt("blitz"), ChartUtils.pickColor()).setLabel(activity.getString(R.string.blitz)));
        if (values.getInt("ranked")>0)sliceValue.add(new SliceValue(values.getInt("ranked"), ChartUtils.pickColor()).setLabel(activity.getString(R.string.ranked)));
        if (values.getInt("casual")>0)sliceValue.add(new SliceValue(values.getInt("casual"), ChartUtils.pickColor()).setLabel(activity.getString(R.string.casual)));
        if (values.getInt("royal")>0)sliceValue.add(new SliceValue(values.getInt("royal"), ChartUtils.pickColor()).setLabel(activity.getString(R.string.royal)));

        PieChartData dataPie = new PieChartData();
        dataPie.setHasLabels(true);
        dataPie.setValues(sliceValue);

        holder2.chartPie.setPieChartData(dataPie);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;

    case 3:
        ViewHolder3 holder3 = (ViewHolder3)holder;

        List<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
        Axis axisX = new Axis().setHasLines(true);
        Axis axisY = new Axis().setHasLines(true).setHasTiltedLabels(false);
        try {
        Line line = new Line((ArrayList) values.get("valuesLine"));

        line.setHasPoints(false);
        line.setColor(ChartUtils.pickColor());
        lines.add(line);
        axisX.setName("Games");
        axisY.setName("Progress");
        LineChartData dataLine = new LineChartData();
        dataLine.setAxisYLeft(axisY);
        dataLine.setAxisXBottom(axisX);
        dataLine.setLines(lines);

        holder3.chartLine.setLineChartData(dataLine);
        holder3.chartLine.setZoomEnabled(false);
        holder3.chartLine.setInteractive(true);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
}

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
return 4;
}

public static class ViewHolder0 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

ImageView player_skilltier;
TextView player_lifetimegold;
TextView player_games_played;
TextView player_games_won;

ViewHolder0(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    player_skilltier = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_player_skilltier);
    player_lifetimegold = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_player_lifetimegold);
    player_games_played = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_player_gamesplayed);
    player_games_won = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_player_gameswon);

}

}

public static class ViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
TextView winPercent;
TextView wins_defeats;
public ViewHolder1(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    winPercent = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_win_percent);
    wins_defeats = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_win_defeat);
}
}
 public static class ViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
  PieChartView chartPie;

  public ViewHolder2(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    chartPie = (PieChartView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.chartGameMode);
}
}
public static class ViewHolder3 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
LineChartView chartLine;
public ViewHolder3(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    chartLine = (LineChartView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.chartStreak);
}
}
```

I shot two screencasts, in this video [tap](https://youtu.be/T4fdn3PAgQQ) the timeline of gpu, on the second [tap](https://youtu.be/LHgzZzEpFQQ) the screen flashes when the item is updated. On both strange things happen. What is the problem?

Comment: Probably the libraries you are using to display pie chart and graphs are taking too much time to process. So don't initialize any new variables in onBindView of RecyclerView.  Either initialize them on a separate thread or process them before and pass them as a parameter to the adapter. And for better performance, In onBindView , never initialize any variables. Just bind the data don't process it. Use setVisibility to show and hide views.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to parse your JSONObject into a ArrayList before instantiate your adapter in your RecyclerView, and access each item from your ArrayList, it might cause performances problems.
You can do it with Gson :

```java
Gson gson = new Gson();
TypeToken<ArrayList<YourValue>> token = new TypeToken<ArrayList<YourValue>>() {};
ArrayList<YourValue> listValues = gson.fromJson(values.toString(), token.getType());
```

Comment: it can be the MPAndroidChart that takes so much time to load charts, i suggest you to create a new Activity/Fragment onItemClick, to display the chart instead of display it in your RecyclerView